# Cannot start a Tomcat server with the Community Server Connectors extension in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tomcat, vscode-extensions, community-server

In VS Code I have created a Maven project for a Java Servlet (no Spring) and now I try to deploy the generated `.war` file to a local Tomcat 8.5 via the [Community Server Connectors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-community-server-connector) extension.

However when the extension loads I always get an error balloon with the message:

> Unable to start the RSP server:  Extension backend error - rsp error - community server connector failed to start - typeerror: cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

And then when I try to click the *Create New Server* icon I get as a subsequent message:

> Unable to create the server:  Extension backend error - there are no rsp providers to choose from.

Any idea why this happens and how I can fix this? Or how can I debug this in more detail?

Comment: Its issues should be sent to https://github.com/redhat-developer/rsp-server-community/issues and if you like you can check out the code and debug on your own.

Comment: @LexLi Thx for chiming in. I posted it here first, because this might not be an issue of the extension, but a setup problem other people have encounter as well -- and maybe solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seem to have been that I had used Java 8 as the JDK.

I now switched to a Java 17 JDK for VS Code - and it works: I can create a new Tomcat server under the "Servers - Community Server Connector" heading and start it successfully up.